# Installing the mysql-php module o

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-ec2

im trying to install mysql-php on ec2 amazon free tier but for some reason cant do it, I have installed everything else besides and that is the last thing stoping me from getting the server up and running - the error is attached below

```
[root@ip-10-244-45-91 /]# yum install mysql-php
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                             | 2.3 kB     00:00
248 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
No package mysql-php available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name is `php-mysql` or `php-mysqlnd` not `mysql-php`